# What does "Fun!" mean when it is said just by itself?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, expressions

An example from Modern Family:

```
Woman1: Desiree just moved in down the block
Man: Fun! Where?
Woman2: 314
```

An example from The Office:

```
Micheal: Look (He is pointing out a bottle of wine that has been given to him)
Erin: Fun!
```

I don't understand the expression in those two examples because it doesn't make any sense with the meaning of the "Fun" word.

Is it something like "How nice!" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is similar to "How nice!". More accurately, it can be understood as "[That is] fun!". It is worth noting that "Fun!" is often used sarcastically (though it seems from the context that this is not the case in the two cited examples).

Comment: This sort of usage is very common, both sarcastically and seriously: "Great!" "Amazing!" "Awesome!" "Lucky!" as well as in a lot of other variants.